# How to remove bolding from a fraction that has no entity in HTML

Tags: html, unicode, fractions

When using the fraction such as 1/8 it is bolded in my browser (latest version of chrome). The HTML code I am using is `&frac18` 
I believe that this is happening because it has no entity, since 1/2, 1/4, and 1/3 display with no issues. How can display this value without bolding?

Comment: have you tried applying any styles? also I don't believe that &frac18; exists

Comment: I could make changes with css but I wanted to know if I could only use unicode. It seems that is not possible then.

Comment: correction &frac18; only exists in some fonts. so you may try just setting a style to use one of those fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the entity does not exist in all typefaces you may have to select a font where that font does exist and apply a style that forces it show

```css
p{
  font-family:serif;
}
.fraction {
  font-weight:400;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<p>here is a line of text</p>
<p>with some fractions <span class="fraction">&frac18; <span  </p>
```